# Issue with WP_Query (need a array of selected ID's)

Tags: wp-query, loop, array, id

Today I have

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'inspirations', 'posts_per_page' => 50 ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
```

which gives me all posts inside the tax `inspiration` - I need to alter this, so that I get only selected ID's in my array, ex. 4714, 3608, instead of all terms of the tax.

According to [WP Query arguments](http://www.billerickson.net/code/wp_query-arguments/) I need to alter the code to:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_in' => array(4174, 3608), 'posts_per_page' => 50 ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
```

But that does not return anything, not even a error.. What am I doing wrong here? :)

Thanks a lot for reading.

Comment: There is nothing in your code about terms, so I don't quite follow what do you mean around "all terms of the tax" part.

Comment: sorry, I meant posts of the tax. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which gives me all posts inside the tax inspiration - I need to alter this, so that I get only selected ID's in my array, ex. 4714, 3608, instead of all terms of the tax.

I'm assuming you mean that this query gives you all posts inside *post type* inspiration and you want to pull specific post IDs instead of all *posts* of the *post type*. [Taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) and [Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types). are two different things.

Try to alter your query to something like this:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'inspirations',
    'post__in' => array( 4174, 3608 )
));
```

The difference between this and your original loop is that 1) There is a post type defined and 2) `post__in` has 2 underscore where yours has 1. I removed the `posts_per_page` parameter as this query should only return 2 posts.